# Database design, multiple M-M tables or just one?

Tags: database, database-design, many-to-many

Today I was designing a database for a potential personal project of mine. Since I couldn't decide what would be a better option I asked my teacher Databases, unfortunately he couldn't tell me which of the two options is better than the other and why.

I designed the database for a dummy data generator. Since I want to generate multilangual data I thought of these tables. (But its a simplification of the tables).

(first and last)**names**: id, name
**streets**: id, name
**languages**: id, name

Each names.name and streets.name originates from a language, sometimes a name can have multiple origins (ex: Nick is both a Dutch as an English name).
Each language has multiple names and streets.

These two rules result in a Many-to-Many relationship. At the moment I've got only two tables, but I know I will get between 10 and 20 of these kind of tables.
The regular way one would do this is just make 10 to 20 Many-to-Many relationship tables.
Another idea I came up with was just one Many-to-Many table with a third column which specifies which table the id relates to.

At the moment I've got the design on my other PC so I will update it with my ideas visualized after dinner (2 hours or so).

Which idea is better and why?

---

To make the project idea a bit clearer:
It is always a hassle to create good and enough realistic looking working data for projects. This application will generate this data for you and return the needed SQL so you only have to run the queries.

The user comes to the site to get the data. He states his tablename, his columnnames and then he can link the columnnames to types of data, think of:
 * Firstname
 * Lastname
 * Email adress (which will be randomly generated from the name of the person)
 * Adress details (street, housenumber, zipcode, place, country)
 * A lot more

Then, after linking columns with the types the user can set the number of rows he wants to make. The application will then choose a country at random and generate realistic looking data according to the country they live in.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see your problem. The m-n relationships would appear to be between Names and Languages. Streets have a name which would relate back to Names. If you want the language of the name, use the existing m-n relationship. So if you create a Cities table--which, of course, has a name--the name also relates back to the Names table and so forth. There is one relationship between Names and Languages. All entities that use names can use that relationship, they don't need their own.

Comment: There is no relation between names (which is first and lastnames) table and the streetnames table. I should have made that clearer in the question.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. First and last names are attributes of people (customers, employees, clients, whatever) and don't go into a separate table. The only time you would place names in their own table would be to supply other data about names -- such as language of origin. If you have an attribute in Streets that specifies the language of another attribute then you have a normalization problem. If you specify this relationship through a cross table, then you may as well create a Names table for a name entity and define each name/language relationship once and be done with it.

Comment: Im making a database to generate dummy data, for that Im gonna choose a country random from the DB,  see what languages are spoken in that country and use the names,  addresses, and other information from those languages. So Im not saving people, but names which I use to create random data which I will export as SQL so other people can use the dummy data generated with my application

Comment: I just edited my question, it now contains a better description of the project as well.

Comment: So the name/language relationship is only needed when generating the data? If so, again, you only need a table of names, a table of languages and then relate them through an intersection table. Of course, you will probably want to tag a name as F, L or P for First (Sam, Pedro, etc.), Last (Smith, Da Vinci, etc.) or Place (Pittsburg, Berlin, etc.). You could get really fancy for names like Thomas which can be both First and Last or York which could be Last and Place, but for data generation, you probably don't need that level of sophistication.

Comment: This is an whole other option, I havent thought of this, might be a really good idea, will think about it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually an excellent question.  This sort of thing leads to a genuine problem in database design and there is a real tradeoff.  I don't know what rdbms you are using but....

Basically you have four choices, all of them with serious downsides:
**1.**  One M-M table with check constraints that only one fkey can be filled in besides language and one column per potential table.  Ick....
**2.**  One M-M table per relationship.  This makes things quite hard to manage over time especially if you need to change something from an int to a bigint at some point.
**3.**  One M-M table with a polymorphic relationship.  You lose a lot of referential integrity checks when you do this and to make it safe, have fun coding (and testing!) triggers.
**4.**  Look carefully at the advanced features in your rdbms for a solution.  For example in `postgresql` this can be solved with table inheritance.  The downside is that you lose portability and end up in advanced territory.

Unfortunately there is no single definite answer.  You need to consider the tradeoffs carefully and decide what makes sense for your project.  If I was just working with one RDBMS, I would do the last one.  But if not, I would probably do one table per relationship and focus on tooling to manage the problems that come up.  But the former preference is about my level of knowledge and confidence, and the latter is a bit more of a personal opinion.

So I hope this helps you look at the tradeoffs and select what is right for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I gave you an upvote for now,  will do a bit more research with the information you got me. Will mark it as answer later on (if nobody else gives an even more clear message that is)

Comment: I just did some reading up on the mentioned options and I think I'm gonna go for option 3. I was planning on using Laravel which has some nice tools for the M-M polymorphic relationships. https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations